# Different implementations of opening files

Tags: operating-system, system-calls

I am reading the book "Operating System Concepts by Galvin" and encountered the following statement:

> File open can be implemented in any of two ways:
>
> 1. Some system open files when it is referenced first time. And closes them, once the job is done.
> 2. Some other systems allow application programmers to specify a order such as open-read/write-close in application itself."

I see C programs with Linux/Windows follows the second method.

- Are there any examples of the first method?
- Why are those systems using the first method?

Comment: Do IBM mainframe systems with JCL that specifies which files are connected to which channel number count as an illustration of the first technique?

Comment: I think that this is what is being referred to in #1. From back in the days when the olde FORTRAN and COBOL had no OPEN statements.

Answer (score 0):

In understanding the two implementations and their pros/cons, I think it's useful to generalize here:

1. Generalize from the file concept to consider really any acquired resource; and
2. Generalize from what the operating system provides, to what's also provided by the programming language, libraries, or frameworks used.

As to why systems may use the first method...

The answer would similarly apply to why you may want to use a programming idiom like [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). I.e. do you want to do your own life cycle management of the resource or do you want it done for you.

Sometimes when life cycle management is done for us (us as programmers), we may lose the ability to do things that we want (things which might otherwise be possible if we implement the life cycle management ourselves). Sometimes it's more important to be unable to possibly leak a resource than it is to be able to access every bell and whistle for it.

Take memory management in C++ for example. We can allocate memory from the system using `new` or we can instead call `std::make_shared`. The former however requires us to also call `delete` (at the end of its use) if we want to ensure the memory isn't leaked. Meanwhile Java doesn't give the programmer direct access to allocating memory and instead employs garbage collection so that ["programmers can be spared the burden of having to perform manual memory management"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)#Automatic_memory_management).

As to examples of the first method...

Many Unix-like operating systems provide a programmatic interface to the `syslog` facility. While it has *open* and *close* like analogies in `openlog` and `closelog`, calling these is optional. One can just simply call `syslog` to start system logging text.

Standard input and output similarly is also managed for us. When a program starts up, it typically already has these concepts opened and available. When it exits, those streams will be closed for us (as necessary). Programs don't need to call `fclose(stdout)` (nor something like `fopen("/dev/console")`). Programs can just call `fputs` or `fgets` using `stdout` or `stdin`.